# 'Dimension' meaning size or length

Tags: word-usage

I'm quite sure it is correct to say "The **dimensions** of this box are 10 cm x 15 cm x 20 cm." But I think a sentence like "The **dimension** of this box in the given direction is 20 cm" is not commonly used. But is it also wrong semantically or grammatically?

Comment: It is grammatical.  Whether it's "wrong semantically" depends on what you mean by "wrong". If you mean not immediately clear, then it's "wrong". A reader or listener might wonder why you're avoiding the word "height" -- maybe you mean something subtle that they're overlooking or not grasping.

Comment: @TimR, let's replace 'vertical direction' with 'x direction' (x being the x axis in mathematical sense).

Comment: @apadana Isn't the x-axis usually one of the 2 horizontal axis and the z-axis is the vertical one?

Comment: "dimension...in the x direction" strikes me as rather wonky and unnatural.  It would come down to the expectations of your audience, who may understand why you're avoiding the word "height".

Answer (score 2):

It's fine.
The NOW corpus has 4033 instances of "the dimension of" (though looking through them I haven't found many instances used in the way you suggest: most are metaphorical).